# How to make a zoo in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a whole lot of animals (10-15) sitting in a room waiting for a dungeon master on Dwarf Fortress, and I'd like to do something with them, like make a zoo. On [this page](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Captured_creatures) it says,

> Zoo areas may be defined from a built
> cage via the <kbd>q</kbd> menu for the enjoyment
> of your dwarves. Be aware that dwarves
> will receive happy or unhappy thoughts
> from seeing an animal in a zoo based
> on their preferences. Owning the cage
> containing a loved animal is even
> better.

I'm looking at my cages and I don't see this...are zoo removed/changed in the newest version? On it's talk page it said they just copied the page over from the older version.

Comment: Cages confused me initially because I didn't realize they can be furniture or buildings.  Initially, you build a cage and it goes in the trap.  It catches something and is removed and probably put in an animal storage area.

You can then "build" a Cage building, which will ask for a cage furniture as a component.  Once the cage is built, it has new options, like making a zoo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, zoos are still existent. You have to make sure that your cage is built and define a <kbd>r</kbd>oom from them, just like you would with a bedroom or a dining room.

Comment: oh, yeah, I had them built, but I figured defining a room was just for putting people in them.(At least that's what I assumed setting someone as the owner would do.)

Comment: You don't have to assign anyone as the owner. You can make it a meeting hall if you want, give your dorfs happy thoughts.

Comment: Psh, why use words like "existent" when words like "extant" are around!:P Extant -- the opposite of Extinct! As in, my dwarves were extant... until I had some 'fun'.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's what I did. That's just why it initially confused me.

Comment: @Raven Because neither zoos nor dwarves are documents.